# Why does PasswordDerivedBytes produces different key everytime if I use HMACSha1 as hashing algorithm?

Tags: c#, encryption, cryptography, encryption-symmetric

I am using same passphrase and salt, yet it produces different keys everytime I run it when using PasswordDerivedBytes. It produces same key everytime if I use Sha1, however. Why is that?

And why does Rfc2898DerivedBytes produce same key everytime if I use that same passphrase, salt, initvector combination, knowing that it uses HMACSha1?

Code snippet added below-

```
string passPhrase = "passPhrase";
byte[] saltBytes = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes("saltValue");
int iterations = 2;
int keySize = 32;
string hashAlgo = "HMACSHA1";

Rfc2898DeriveBytes derivedBytes = new Rfc2898DeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltBytes, iterations);
byte[] keyBytes = derivedBytes.GetBytes(keySize);

PasswordDeriveBytes password = new PasswordDeriveBytes(passPhrase, saltBytes, hashAlgo, iterations);
byte[] keyBytes2 = password.GetBytes(keySize);
```

Comment: @ArtjomB. Added on post.

Comment: [Here is a dotnetfiddle of the program](https://dotnetfiddle.net/44HWUG), hit `Run` multiple times and you will see different outputs.

Comment: `PasswordDerivedBytes` has many issues. It is a MS extension of PBKDF1 that is not well defined if you use more bytes than the output defined by the hash algorithm that you put in. As nobody (not even the Mono devs) knows the broken algorithm you are screwed if you ever want to create the same result using another runtime. If you use SHA1 and first request 16 bytes and then another 16 bytes then the values differ from asking 32 bytes at once and splitting them. Use `Rfc2898DeriveBytes` instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`Rfc2898DerivedBytes` uses PBKDF2 with HMAC-SHA-1 as PRF (A PRF is essentially a keyed hash). PBKDF2 expects a PRF and uses the key for the password and the salt/chaining value as message.

`PasswordDeriveBytes` uses PBKDF1 with a user specified hash algorithm. This hash is expected to be unkeyed. But you passed in "HMACSHA1" which is keyed. When creating an instance of HMACSHA1, .NET fills in a random key. Since `PasswordDeriveBytes` is not key aware (it expects an unkeyed hash), it ends up with a differently hash function each time and thus produces different results each time.

Comment: "`PasswordDeriveBytes` uses PBKDF2" should probably be "`PasswordDeriveBytes` uses PBKDF1".

Comment: @owlstead Of course. Strictly speaking it only uses PBKDF1 for the first output block and something homebrew for the rest.

Comment: @owlstead Personally I'd read exactly the native output size and then use HKDF no matter if it's PBKDF2 or PBKDF1.

Comment: Yeah, that's probably the best method, I think history shows us agreeing on this :)